# Get volume ID of root volume in AWS EC2 using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm creating EC2 instances in AWS using python. I want to list the root volume ID of the instances I'm creating. I'm creating the instances with only the root volume. No additional EBS volumes are attached.

After I create the instance and have the instance ID, here is my attempt to get the volume ID for the root volume:

```
instance_list = []
volume_list = [] 
if instances:
    for instance in instances:
        instance_id = instance.instance_id
        instance_list.append(instance_id)
        root_volume = ec2_client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId=instance_id, Attribute='blockDeviceMapping')
         volume_list.append(root_volume)
         print(f"Volumes: {root_volume} Volumes Type: {type(root_volume)}")
```

The response that I get back from that print statement is:

```
Volumes: {'BlockDeviceMappings': [], 'InstanceId': 'i-0930a235f6b1c47b2', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'bb679ad1-5c81-461f-b5e6-427bc140df68', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '299', 'date': 'Tue, 21 Jan 2020 21:22:16 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}} Volumes Type: <class 'dict'>
```

The `BlockDeviceMappings` are empty.

However when I look at the instance in the console I can see it has a toot volume id of `vol-02ebd87bcf9bf62be`. How can I arrive at the volume ID of the instance root volume programmatically using python?

Comment: The basic boto3 calls you're using work for me with both a running and a stopped EC2 instance, both of which have a single EBS root volume. In both cases I see a `BlockDeviceMappings` key which yields an array of one EBS volume info with a `VolumeId`. Is your boto3 package up to date? PS why are you surrounding the call to `ec2_client.describe_instance_attribute()` with parens?

Comment: ok thanks. Maybe I need a time delay before I grab the volume ID? Because as I am currently doing this the `BlockDeviceMappings` are blank for the instance id. I am wrapping the call in parens because I was initially trying to get at the `BlockDeviceMappings` directly but removed that when the command wasn't working so I could see what was in the raw value.

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary parens in the OP.

Comment: Yep. Adding a time delay of 30 seconds worked! I will try bumping down the time delay to see how quickly I can retrieve the info. Just curious. Were you using a time delay as well?

Comment: The volume info also shows up for an EC2 instance that I just launched (still in initializing state). This is in us-east-1, but I doubt that's relevant. You presumably have a reasonably up to date boto3 package. If you use the awscli, does it work? For example: `aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --attribute blockDeviceMapping --instance-id i-0930a235f6b1c47b2`

Comment: I ran the script within 10 seconds of launch and it gave me the VolumeId no problem. You might want to look into tying your device mapping request into one of the instance waiters ('instance_exists', 'instance_running', 'instance_status_ok') to see if you can optimize better than 'wait 30 seconds'.

Comment: OK so some time delay is obviously important. Because if I give the command to list the volumes immediately after it's created the `BlockDeviceMappings` are empty. I'll experiment to see how quickly I can get a valid `BlockDeviceMappings`.

Comment: Hmm... it seems that even a delay of 1 second works. Problem solved! Thanks for your help!